# Gatsby, RSS Feeds and a Headless CMS

Tags: gatsby, contentful, strapi, prismic.io, headless-cms

I am building a site using Gatsby and have a 'News' section of the site.  This section is to be populated by various news articles pulled in from different RSS feeds.

However, I do not want to include every article from every feed and I want to have some editorial control (for example: modifying Headlines, adding an introductory line, etc).

Is it possible to do this vis-a-vis some sort of Headless CMS (like Contentful or Prismic)?

If so, any idea how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing that there might be a way to do this with Integration Fields in Prismic, basically connect your repository to an external API. So you have this content available in Prismic, and you can add/edit field from the CMS

Here's the documentation: https://user-guides.prismic.io/en/articles/1401183-connect-to-a-custom-api

Comment: Thanks -- I'll take a look at it.  Sounds like what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The Cosmic JS [Headless CMS](https://cosmicjs.com) provides a [Gatsby-Source-Plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-cosmicjs/) plus content editing capabilities via the [web-based Dashboard](https://cosmicjs.com/headless-cms). You could also build a custom [Extension](https://cosmicjs.com/docs/extensions/) to handle your external APIs within the Cosmic Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

The [Strapi CMS](https://strapi.io/) provides a [Gatsby-Source-Strapi](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-strapi/) or dynamic requests by [Graphql](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/graphql.html#usage) or REST.

The content you could edit by WYSWIG edytor.
[image]